# Passing @Binding variable from protocol var to if in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a model like this:

```swift
protocol PurchasableProduct {
    var randomId: String { get }
}

class Cart: Identifiable {
    var items: [PurchasableProduct]
    
    init(items: [PurchasableProduct]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

class Product: Identifiable, PurchasableProduct {
    var randomId = UUID().uuidString
    var notes: String = ""
}

class DigitalGood: Identifiable, PurchasableProduct {
    var randomId = UUID().uuidString
}
```

where `items` conform to protocol `PurchasableProduct`.

I want to build a View that shows cart like this:

```swift
struct CartView: View {
    @State var cart: Cart
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(cart.items.indices) { index in
                CartItemView(item: self.$cart.items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `CartItemView` is:

```swift
struct CartItemView: View {
    @Binding var item: PurchasableProduct
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.item is Product {
                Text("Product")
            } else {
                Text("Digital Good")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's working and give me result as
[This (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raWm7.png)

But I want to extend this a but more that my `items` element can be passed as a binding variable lets say as:

```swift
struct CartItemView: View {
    @Binding var item: PurchasableProduct
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.item is Product {
                VStack {
                    TextField("add notes", text: (self.$item as! Product).notes) // ❌ Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
                    TextField("add notes", text: (self.$item as! Binding<Product>).notes) // ⚠️ Cast from 'Binding<PurchasableProduct>' to unrelated type 'Binding<Product>' always fails
                }
            } else {
                Text("Digital Good")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. I have a collection of items that depends on a class should be drawn differently
2. Items have different editable sync that should be binded into `CartView`

Not sure if thats syntax issue or my approach issue ... how to cast this on `body` to get the correct view based on type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a custom binding:

```
struct CartItemView: View {
    @Binding var item: PurchasableProduct

    var product: Binding<Product>? {
        guard item is Product else { return nil }
        return .init(
            get: {
                self.$item.wrappedValue as! Product
            }, set: {
                self.$item.wrappedValue = $0
            }
        )
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if product != nil {
                TextField("add notes", text: product!.notes)
            } else {
                Text("Digital Good")
            }
        }
    }
}
```